Sum of subgradients
Usually, this theorem is defined using proper extended functions as follows:
Theorem 2.85 (Nonlinear optimization Ruszczyński). Assume that $ f = f_1 + f_2 $, where $ f_1: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} $ and $ f_2: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} $ are convex proper functions. If there exists a point $ x_0 \in \text{dom} \, f $ such that $ f_1 $ is continuous at $ x_0 $, then
$$
\partial f(x) = \partial f_1(x) + \partial f_2(x), \quad \text{for all } x \in \text{dom} \, f.
$$
For pedagogical purposes, I want to write it avoiding extended functions and also explicitly stating the domain of f_1 and f_2. This is the result:
Moreau-Rockafellar: Assume $ f_1: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $ f_2: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ are convex functions defined on non-empty subsets $ S $ and $ D $ of $ \mathbb{R}^n $, respectively. Define $ f: S \cap D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $ f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) $. If there exists a point $ x_0 \in S \cap D $ such that $ f_1 $ is continuous at $ x_0 $, then the subdifferential of $ f$ at any point$ x \in S \cap D $ is given by
$$
\partial f(x) = \partial f_1(x) + \partial f_2(x),
$$
where the subdifferentials are calculated within their respective domains.
Is this correct?

Two corrections:
First, $S,D$ need to be convex sets.
Second, one needs  that $x_0$ is an interior point of $S$.
How would you define continuity of $f_1$ at $x_0$ on $S$? The statement of the theorem is wrong if you assume $f_1$ to be continuous from the metric space $(S, \|\cdot\|_2)$ to $\mathbb R$.

I understand the first two observations. I do not understand exactly the third observation. From what I understand, when you define an extended function the only thing you are doing is simplifying notation, that is: one starts with a function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$, $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and then set $+\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\X$. Perhaps I am not completely understanding the condition "If there exists a point $x_0 \in \text{dom}(f)$ such that $f_1$ is continuous at $x_0$"

If $f_1$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $x_0$ belongs to the interior of $dom(f)$. The function $f_1(x) = -\sqrt x$ on $S=[0,+\infty)$ is continuous at $x_0=0$ (when considered as a function from the metric space $S$ to $\mathbb R$), however, sum rule fails at $x_0$ for $f_2(x):=f_1(-x)$.

Ok, I see.
Just to double-check: If I add the conditions 1) $S, D$ convex sets, 2) $x_0$ is an interior point of S, then is the formulation I propose correct?

yes, it is. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Thanks! Still, I don't see why the original formulation (Theorem 2.85 (Nonlinear optimization Ruszczyński). ) is correct, since it does not distinguish interior points.

because continuity at $x_0$ implies that $x_0$ is an interior point of the domain.
